# Change install path in Gambas

Tags: packaging

I am writing an application in Gambas for inclusion in the software center in Ubuntu. I just got told that the only thing missing in my application, is that it should install into /opt/whatever. Unfortunately, I cannot seem to find out how to change that path in Gambas. Does anyone know how?

Rasmus